# Root CA best practice

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

We are planning a new PKI for our company.

Existing structure is a single root CA and two issuing CA's. One for test, one for production.

We can keep the new PKI design the same or we can use another design. One design that came up is using several root CA's, each with a single issuing CA designed for a specific purpose. Typically, one for Citrix, one for Intune one for test purposes one for Linux and so one.

Is this a good idea or should we stick to one root CA and use whatever number of issuing CA's we like?

Comment: What do you see as the advantage of having multiple issuing CAs?

Comment: It might be wiser to have a separate Root CA for your test environments.  You can have less/minimal governance on issuance from that one and its subordinates, while retaining good governance of the production chain.

Answer (score 1):

To the great extent it is opinion based. Consider following aspects:

**Own root CA vs. well-known root CA**

What is the goal of having your own CA at all? Some applications use system wide trust stores, some (like Java) use their own trust stores. Browsers and many other applications will not trust your certificates. To make your CA trusted, you will have to install certificates in trust stores of every application you need on every device (PCs, laptops, smartphones) of every user.

If you control all devices, it is fine. But if not, then many users may refuse to install your root CA certificate, because they may be afraid of huge security problems. Namely, that you don't have strict security measures and that somebody can compromise your root CA easily and issue certificates for any other web sites and can use them for man-in-the-middle attacks.

A possible alternative for having your own root CA: Let some well known CA to issue a CA certificate to your company. This is not trivial. Your company will have to prove that it can follow corresponding CA processes and strict security guidelines. For intermediate CA you will just revoke its certificate in such case.

**Intermediate CA vs. root CA**

If you nevertheless decide to use your own root CA, there is no need to have many root CAs. The less you use your root CA private key, the more secure it remains. That's why establish also an intermediate CA and issue a certificate to it using your root CA. For issuing certificates for particular hosts use this intermediate CA. An intermediate CA will allow you to reduce the efforts for installing CA certificates on all needed devices each time you believe the CA was compromised.

**Same CA for all environments**

I don't see any benefits in using separate CAs for different types of environments. This will make the process more complex and more error prone. If you believe that the intermediate CA was compromised, revoke its certificate and issue a new one.